# I need to query for a set of objects whose primary keys are contained inside of a list

Tags: python, django

As the title says, I need a way to perform this query.  I have tried the following:

```
user_list_ids = []
user_lists = []

user_entries = OwnerEntry.objects.filter(name=request.user)

for user in user_entries:
    user_list_ids.append(user.list_id)

user_lists = ListEntry.objects.filter(id__in=user_list_ids)

for user in user_entries:
        user_list_ids.append(user.list_id)

user_lists = ListEntry.objects.filter(id__in=user_list_ids)
```

However, I get an error on the last line:  int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'ListEntry'

Here are the relevant models:

```
class OwnerEntry(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    list_id = models.ForeignKey(ListEntry)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)

class ListEntry(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    # active_date = models.DateTimeField('date of last list activity')
    expire_date = models.DateField('date of expiration')
    create_date = models.DateField('date created')
```

Answer (score 2):

to answer your question directly, please note that you have a `list_id` rather than `list` as a ForeignKey name (`OwnerEntry` model). In order to actually extract the fk value, you should use `list_id_id` instead (or rename `list_id` to `list` ;))

Please also note that django supports object references, like so:

`someowner = OwnerEntry.objects.get( ... )
ownerslist = someowner.listentry_set.all()`

cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can define OwnerEntry's foreign key to ListEntry as :

```
list_id = models.ForeignKey(ListEntry, related_query_name='owner_entry')
```

and then do this one-liner in your code:

```
user_lists = ListEntry.objects.filter(owner_entry__name=request.user)
```

What this does is exactly filter every ListEntry which has at least one owner_entry whose name is equal to request.user's.
The redefinition of the foreign key is just for the sake of giving a nice name to the query attribute.

For more details on queries that work with backward relationships: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships